# Top part of my website disappears when I resize it vertically

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a responsive log in page for a college, but when I resize the window vertically the logo and basically the top part disappears.

Currently I'm designing for an iPhone 7 using the dev tools in Google Chrome to help me with the view. When I open the website on my Huawei phone and tap the password field the keyboard pushes the page up and the logo partially disappears. This does not happen on my iPhone.

I think the problem is somewhere in my div elements. Sorry if its a dumb question, I'm a beginner.

Website: https://borislav1333.000webhostapp.com/

```css
body
{
 margin: 0;
}

img
{
 max-width: 300px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 60px;
 left: 37px;
 z-index: 1;

}

.container
{
 width: 375px;
 height: 667px;
 background-color: white;
 margin: auto;
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 font-family: Georgia;
}

.form-back
{
 width: 200px;
 background-color: white;
 z-index: 1;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 45px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 80%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -80%);
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 18px;
}


input[type=text], input[type=password]
{
 width: 100%;
 padding: 10px;
 margin: 8px 0px 8px;
 border: solid 1px #aaa; 
 border-radius: 4px;
}

button
{
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 30px;
 border-color: white;
 background-color: #e52791;
 font-family: Georgia;
 transition: background-color 0.7s ease-out;
}

button:hover
{
 background-color: #02356a;
 color: white;
 transition: background-color 0.7s ease;
}

.submit
{
 position: relative;
 top: 30px;
}

::placeholder
{
 font-family: georgia;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="img"><img src="logo.jpg"></div>

 <div class="form-back">
  <form action="message.html" onsubmit="return validation()">
    <div>
     <label for="accountNum">Metric Number</label><br>
     <input type="text" id="accountNum" name="accountNum" placeholder="Metric Number..."><br>
    </div>

    <div>
     <label for="surname">Password:</label><br>
     <input type="password" id="surname" name="surname" placeholder="Password..."><br>
    </div>

    <div class="submit">
     <button type="submit">Log In</button>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your code you have used position absolute value in many elements. I think this problem which you are facing is happening due to this absolute. I have updated your CSS code and added snippet below. Replace it and check, I wish you problem will be resolved :

```css
         body
          {
              margin: 0;
          }

          img
          {
              width: 100%;
              max-width: 300px;
              z-index: 1;
              margin: 0 auto;
          }

          .container
          {
              margin: 0 auto;
              font-family: Georgia;
              text-align: center;
          }

          .form-back
          {
              width: 100%;
              
              background:transparent;
              margin: 0 auto;
              padding: 45px;
              text-align: center;
              font-size: 18px;
          }


          input[type=text], input[type=password]
          {
              width: 100%;
              padding: 10px;
              margin: 8px 0px 8px;
              border: solid 1px #aaa; 
              border-radius: 4px;
          }

          button
          {
              width: 100%;
              height: 50px;
              border: none;
              border-radius: 30px;
              border-color: white;
              background-color: #e52791;
              font-family: Georgia;
              transition: background-color 0.7s ease-out;
          }

          button:hover
          {
              background-color: #02356a;
              color: white;
              transition: background-color 0.7s ease;
          }

          .submit
          {
              position: relative;
              top: 30px;
          }

          ::placeholder
          {
              font-family: georgia;
          }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
    <div class="img"><img src="https://borislav1333.000webhostapp.com/logo.jpg"></div>

    <div class="form-back">
        <form action="message.html" onsubmit="return validation()">
                <div>
                    <label for="accountNum">Metric Number</label><br>
                    <input type="text" id="accountNum" name="accountNum" placeholder="Metric Number..."><br>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label for="surname">Password:</label><br>
                    <input type="password" id="surname" name="surname" placeholder="Password..."><br>
                </div>

                <div class="submit">
                    <button type="submit">Log In</button>
                </div>
              </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes that fixed the issue with the top of the page disappearing, but when I go into mobile mode the img,input & button are not center aligned.  

https://ibb.co/ykR6Mn2

Comment: That's interesting. I have checked my snippet with same browser settings (iphone 6/7/8). It is working fine on my laptop. I am not sure what is the exact issue. Have you added bootstrap CDN link in the header of the HTML. Might be that's the issue. 
I am adding updating my snippet with bootstrap CDN url. Please check.

Comment: Hi Folk, 
Yes that's correct. Bootstrap CND link is missing in the head of HTML. I have updated my snippet. Please use it.

Comment: Wow thank you for the quick fix!

Can you refer me to a video or explain how that line of code fixed the issue?

Comment: Yea sure, check this video for more information : [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JJSoEo8JSnc)